# Unexpected deadlock in Executor

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, deadlock, executorservice

I found an unexpected deadlock while running tasks in a ThreadPoolExecutor.

The idea is a main task that launches a secondary task that changes a flag.
The main task halts until the secondary task updates the flag.

- If corePoolSize >=2 the main task completes as expected.
- If corePoolSize <2 it seems that the secondary task is enquenqued but never launched.
- Using a SynchronousQueue instead, the main task completes even for corePoolSize=0.

I'd like to know:

- what's the cause of the deadlock?. It seems no obvious from the
  documentation.
- why using a SynchronousQueue instead of a LinkedBlockingQueue prevents the deadlock?
- Is corePoolSize =2 a safe value to prevent this kind of deadlocks?

  ```
  import java.util.concurrent.*;
  class ExecutorDeadlock {
      /*------ FIELDS -------------*/
      boolean halted = true;
      ExecutorService executor;
      Runnable secondaryTask = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("secondaryTask started");
              halted = false;
              System.out.println("secondaryTask completed");
              }
      };
      Runnable primaryTask = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
          System.out.println("primaryTask started");
          executor.execute(secondaryTask);
          while (halted) {
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(500);
              }
              catch (Throwable e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          System.out.println("primaryTask completed");
        }
     };

     /*-------- EXECUTE -----------*/
     void execute(){
          executor.execute(primaryTask);
     }

     /*-------- CTOR -----------*/
     ExecutorDeadlock(int corePoolSize,BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
          this.executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, 4,0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);
     }

     /*-------- TEST -----------*/
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          new ExecutorDeadlock(2,new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()).execute();
          //new ExecutorDeadlock(1,new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()).execute();
         //new ExecutorDeadlock(0,new SynchronousQueue<>()).execute();
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

How do you expect for this to work on threads count <2 if

- You have only 1 executor thread
- first tast adding secondary task to the executor queue and WAITS for it to start

Tasks are fetched from the queue by executor service when there are free executors in pool. In you case (<2) executor thread is never released by first task. 
There is no deadlock issue here.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I'v dug up some info and this is what I have found out. First of all some info from `ThreadPoolExecutor`

> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks.
>   The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> ```
> If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
> If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.
> ```

Ok and now as for queuess `offer` methods

SyncQueue:

> Inserts the specified element into this queue, if another thread is
>   waiting to receive it.

LinkedBlockingQueue

> Inserts the specified element into this queue, waiting if necessary for space to become available.

**return value of `offer` method determines whetever new task will be queued or ran in new thread.**

As `LinkedBlockingQueue` enqueues new task because it can as there is enought capacity, task is enqueued and no new threads are spawn. However `SyncQueu` will not enqueue another task, as there is no other threads that are waiting for something to be enqueued (`offer` returns false as task is not enqueued) and thats why new executor thread will be spawned.

If you read javadocs for `ThreadPoolExecutor` `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `SynchronousQueue` + check implementation of `execute` method, you will get to the same conclusion.

So you were wrong, there is explenation in documentation :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it. Up to 4 threads are allowed to coexist. And also the SyncQueue case...

Comment: I hope that last edit will clearify everything for you

Comment: OK, the secondary task is put in the queue, I already said that in the post. The question is why it is not launched if up to 4 thread are allowed to coexist in the pool (please, note the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor).

Comment: I did explain it tou you. Because if queue is able to accept another task, it will be enqueued and no new thread will be created. Sync queue "cannot" accept task and thats why new thread is spawned and it works for you. In case using sync queue the task IS NOT ADDED TO THE QUEUE. Please read carefully my edit as it took some time to write it, and I cannot repeat myself here in comments. Explanation is there, trust me